# datastax enterprise 5.0 and solr

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I just successfully installed datastax enterprise 5.0 but I can't get solr running

I got "Connection refused" trying to use

> dsetool create_core keyspace.table

Also port 8983 isn't listening

Is there something to do in order to launch the solr service ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah if it's a tarball start with `dse cassandra -s` for search. If it's a package install, edit `/etc/defaults/dse` to have `SOLR_ENABLED=1`

Comment: thanks for the response, but it still doesn't work after SOLR_ENABLED=1 and service dse restart

Comment: As in the process didn't come up?

Comment: actually cassandra doesn't start anymore due to datacenter name changed
Cannot start node if snitch's data center (Solr) differs from previous data center (Cassandra)

Comment: Right changing DC name can cause a short downtime so it's not allowed